# SimpleDateFormat [0] issue

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I've below `SimpleDateFormat` Code

```
Date date = new Date();
DateFormat inpuDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS'Z'");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
String dateStr = inpuDateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
```

It works perfectly on my dev servers but it fails on sandbox instances with following error.

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<...20-08-12T19:06:02.85[0]Z> but was:<...20-08-12T19:06:02.85[]Z>
```

I've handled it as

```
dateStr = dateStr.replace("[0]","");
dateStr = dateStr.replace("[]","");
```

But, I still didn't get the logic why my date is different on different server instances and is there any better way to handle it

Comment: can u post junit specific code

Comment: To print the time zone try to remove the quotes around the 'Z': new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSZ");
But the output of 'Z' is locale specific, so check if your dev server and your sandbox have the same Locale.

Comment: check if output is same for date command in both instances. If different you can align timezones.

Comment: Use `java.time`.

Comment: Agree that serves locale are causing this annoying issue but ```dateStr = dateStr.replace("[0]","");
dateStr = dateStr.replace("[]","");``` should be good idea then? Here my code is unrelavent to Server locale

Comment: Yes, replace() should work as you except. But may it's really better then to post your unit test code, may the issue is there. Or you try to remove the quotes around the 'Z' and run your tests again, may the already work then.

Comment: Yes, please put it as a answer then... It might helpful to someone else also

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, `DateFormat` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first two in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use for example `Instant` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: You have `.SS` in your format pattern string, but there is no way that `SimpleDateFormat` can print (nor parse) two decimals on the seconds. It only supports milliseconds, exactly three decimals, no more, no less.

Comment: The `[0]` is showing you what's wrong - the string doesn't *actually contain* the square brackets. It's saying it expected something ending in `T19:06:02.850Z`, but received something ending in `T19:06:02.85Z`. I suspect that just using `SSS` instead of `S` will fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### java.time

There certainly is a much better way to handle it. Use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work, not `Date`, `DateFormat`, `SimpleDateFormat` nor `Calendar`.

```
    Instant now = Instant.now();
    String dateStr1 = now.toString();
    System.out.println(dateStr1);
```

Output in one run was:

> 2020-07-24T18:06:07.988093Z

You notice that six decimals on the seconds were output, not two. In other runs you may have three decimals or no fraction at all. Don’t worry, for the majority of purposes you’ll be just fine. The format printed is ISO 8601, and according to ISO 8601 the count of decimals on the seconds, even the presence of seconds at all, is optional. So whatever you need the string for, as long as ISO 8601 format is expected, the string from the above code snippet should be accepted.

I am exploiting the fact that `Instant.toString()` produces ISO 8601 format, so we don’t need any formatter.

If for some strange reason you do need exactly two decimals on the seconds, use a formatter for specifying so (edit: now outputting `Z`):

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter2 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSX")
            .withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    String dateStr2 = formatter2.format(now);
    System.out.println(dateStr2);
```

> 2020-07-24T18:06:07.98Z

To a `DateTimeFormatter` (opposite a `SimpleDateFormat`) uppercase `S` in the format pattern string means *fraction of second*, and you are free to place from one through nine of them to get from one to nine decimals.

### What went wrong in your code?

First, the message that you got from your JUnit test was:

> ```
> org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<...20-08-12T19:06:02.85[0]Z> but was:<...20-08-12T19:06:02.85[]Z>
> ```

The square brackets is JUnit’s way of drawing our attention to the difference between the expected and the actual value. So they are not part of those values. What JUnit tells us is that the value was expected to end in `.850Z` but instead ended in just `.85Z`. So a zero was missing. Your test is probably too strict since as I said, it shouldn’t matter whether there are two or three decimals. And `02.85` and `02.850` are just different ways of denoting the exact same value.

This role of the square brackets also explains why replacing `[0]` and `[]` in the string didn’t help: the square brackets were never in the strings, so the replacements never made any change to the strings.

Second, to `SimpleDateFormat` (opposite `DateTimeFormatter`) format pattern letter uppercase `S` means *millisecond*. So putting any other number than three of them makes no sense and gives you incorrect results. In your code you put two. In nine of ten cases the millisecond value is in the interval 100 through 999, and in this case `SimpleDateFormat` prints all three digits in spite of the only two pattern letters `S`. This probably explains why your unit test passed in your development environment. On your sandbox incidentally the time ended in 2.085 seconds. The correct ways to render this include `02.08` and `02.085`. Your `SimpleDateFormat` chose neither. To it the millisecond value of 85 was to be rendered in two positions, so it produces `02.85`, which is the wrong value, 765 milliseconds later. And your unit test objected while this once there were only two decimals, not three.

Third, not what you asked, but no matter if using the troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` or the modern `DateTimeFormatter` you must *never* hardcode `Z` as a literal in the format pattern string. The trailing `Z` means UTC or offset zero from UTC. It needs to be printed (and parsed if that were the case) as an offset, or you get wrong results. The way to make sure you get a `Z` and not for example an offset of `+02:00` is to make sure that an offset of 0 is specified. This was why I put `.withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC)` on my formatter.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove the quotes around the 'Z', as 'Z' is a constant whilst without quotes it means 'time zone':

```
DateFormat inpuDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
```

(By the way, in most cases you want to use three decimal places for milliseconds: "SSS".)

Comment: In one run this gave me a `dateStr` of `2020-07-24T20:48:37.295+0200`. Since the unit test expects the string to end in `Z` it appears to be more wrong than the result I get from the code in the question (for example `2020-07-24T20:49:36.114Z`). As I explain in my answer, you *have got* a point in avoiding putting `Z` in single quotes, only you haven’t found the correct alternative.